# HackerEarth Girlfriend's Demand Challenge

Tags: c, algorithm, runtime-error, time-complexity

The problem description can be found [Here](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/girlfriends-demands/description/). My program is producing outputs that match the sample test cases but when subjected to large integers the program breaks down and I can't figure out the reason. When the data provided by the user is something like , `a:=252509054433933447` `b:=760713016476190629`, the program either stops responding or I get an SIGABRT error or the time for processing 1 input file exceeds maximum allocated time. What is wrong with my code? Can anybody suggest a better algorithm for doing this? Please help me figure out the mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
      long long int a,b,input,len,len1,len2;
      char dem[1000];
      char temp[100000];
      scanf("%s",dem);
      scanf("%u",&input);

      len=strlen(dem);

      for(unsigned int i=0;i<input;i++)
      {
        scanf("\n%lld %lld",&a,&b);

        if(b>len)
        {
          len1=b/len;
          for(unsigned int j=1;j<=((len1+1));j++)
          {
          strcat(temp,dem);
          }
         }
         else
         {
            if(dem[a-1]==dem[b-1])
            {
             printf("\nYes");
            }
            else
            {
              printf("\nNo");
            } 
         }
        len2=strlen(temp);
        if(len2!=0)
        {
        if(temp[a-1]==temp[b-1])
        {
          printf("\nYes");
        }
        else
        {
          printf("\nNo");
        }
        }  

        }

}
```

Comment: `%u` for `long long int`?

Comment: Yeah thats a mistake but don't think it has anything to do with SIGABRT error or time-limit-exceeded output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Wow, that is one misogynistic problem description. That's a shame.*

Your problem is here:

```
for(unsigned int j=1;j<=((len1+1));j++)
{
   strcat(temp,dem);
}
```

You shouldn't concatenate the given string with itself, that will not fit in memory for the given limits. Instead, try to use modulo operations to find what character would be at a certain position if you did actually do the concatenation.

For example, if you had the string `abc` and I asked, what is the character at position 10 in the string formed by repeating `abc` an infinity of times, you'd do (zero-based indexing):

```
char_at_position = str[10 % len(abc)] = str[10 mod 3] = str[1] = b

0123456789 10
abcabcabca b  c
           *
```

Comment: *Wow, that is one misogynistic problem description. That's a shame.* Agreed :/

Comment: hahaha :D so true. Bdw, I tried several times to figure out the logic but I simply can't figure out the pattern which marks the index of the letters of a string. It seems as though the pattern is unrecognizable. :(

Comment: @ArindrajitChakraborty - I posted the pattern too. For their example, note that the length of the string is `5`. `7 mod 5 = 2` and `14 mod 5 = 4`. What are the characters at positions 2 and 4?

Comment: @IVlad Yup if the string is like= vgxgp then at position 2 there is 'g' and at position 4 there is another 'g'. So the output is a yes. Thanks you very much.